# No mapping exists from DbType System.DateTimeOffset to a known SqlCeType

Tags: c#, sql-server, synchronization, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

I have a SQL Server 2008 database that contains DateTimeOffset objects. As per [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172417%28SQL.100%29.aspx),

> SQL Server Compact provides support for replicating the new data types in SQL Server 2008 such as date, time, datetime2, datetimeoffset, geography, and geometry. The new data types in SQL Server 2008 are mapped to nchar, nvarchar, image, etc. For more information about data types in SQL Server 2008, see Data Types in SQL Server 2008 Books Online Documentation.

However, when I use the Microsoft Sync Framework and try to sync my SQL Server database to a SQL Server Compact database, I get the following error:

> No mapping exists from DbType System.DateTimeOffset to a known SqlCeType.

The relevant Microsoft Sync Framework documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726019.aspx). I am on SQL CE 3.5 SP2 and .NET Framework 4.0.

I'm kind of lost here. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of ADO.NET and .Net Compact Framework are you using?  The [docs for Sync FW v2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726019.aspx) and [v2.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726019%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx) indicate that wrt `datetimeoffset`

> If the server provider is hosted on a computer 
>   that is running ADO.NET 2.0 SP1, ADO.NET 2.0 SP1 
>   must also be available on the client for conversion 
>   to succeed. Automatic conversion of datetimeoffset
>   on the client is not supported by .NET
>   Compact Framework 2.0 SP1 or .NET
>   Compact Framework 3.5.

That is consistent with your error.

Comment: I'm running on .NET 4.0 Extended (not Client Profile).

Comment: If your versions are all in good shape - i.e. per docs, this should work - you might have to escalate this to Microsoft. From the above it seems like an area where work may have been done to add support, and maybe it's not working properly.

Comment: Some additional facts -- provisioning the client from the server works fine, and the XML stored in the database maps my column as nchar(34), which is expected. Its only when I actually call the Synchronize method does it get that error.

Answer (score -1):

DateTimeOffset is not supported - the type conversions the doc mention are for Merge Replication, not Sync Framework

Comment: As per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726019.aspx, DateTimeOffset conversion is supported.